# Is that possible to build small modules so that code doesn't repeat with every view

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I have Written code for HTML View with Cakephp 4.x and i would build code so that i don't repeat code i only call a module/element/template or whatever that's called please enlighten me with what that's called as per Cakephp 4.x norms and put together code that doesn't need repeat of code to every view but a call to a module that we can use with our own view with a simple line of code that goes together. in other words written code to module called where ever i require to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use layout as solution. 
Works for every aspect from header to footer, CakePHP strawberry has made a simple solution.